# Find/Replace character in notepad++ using wildcards

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've done some research on this topic, but I've not been able to quite find the exact solution for my particular need. I'm using Notepad++ to write some Z80 assembly code. I need to replace all instances of a ":" character with "::", but only in specific cases. For example, say I have code that looks like this:

```
SomeFunction:
  ld a, whatever
  ret

; Remember to do this: blah blah blah

Function2:
  jr z, someWhere

.subfunction:
  ld hl, somePointer
  ret
```

Normally, I could just go ahead and do Ctrl+H to replace all instances of ":" with "::"...however, in this particular case, I want to avoid replacing the single ":" character on lines which start with either a "." or a ";".  All other instances of ":", change 'em to "::" instead. Essentially, the end result would look like this:

```
SomeFunction::
  ld a, whatever
  ret

; Remember to do this: blah blah blah

Function2::
  jr z, someWhere

.subfunction:
  ld hl, somePointer
  ret
```

Am I making sense? I know I can (and should) use a regular expression for this, and that wildcards would be involved, but am unsure *how* I would go about formatting that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

- Find what: `^(?=[^\;|\.])(.+\:)$`
- Replace with: ``
- Search mode: Regular Expression

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This also check that the colons are not already doubled.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?![;.]).*?(?<!:):\K(?!:)`
- Replace with: `:`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (?![;.])    # negative lookahead, make sure the next character is not ; or .
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    (?<!:)      # negative lookbehind, make sure the previous character is not :
    :           # a colon
    \K          # forget all we have seen until this position
    (?!:)       # negative lookahead, make sure the next character is not :
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]